# Concatenate lists with same .names

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have lists v1 and v2 with the same names:

```
v1: structure(list(ID = c("A1"), Name = c("A2"),.Names = c("ID", "Name") 
    ...
v2: structure(list(ID = c("B1"), Name = c("B2"),.Names = c("ID", "Name")
```

I want to concatenate the lists, while keeping the names, i.e. to get something like:

```
v12:  structure(list(ID = c("A1","B1"), Name = c("A2","B2"), 
.Names = c("ID", "Name")
```

Manual concatenation works:

```
v12<-cbind(Map(c, v1, v2))
```

But, if v1 and v2 are results of applying lapply(), and are stored in a list themselves, the similar logic does not seem to work:

```
v<-lapply(...)
v12<-cbind(Map(c,v))
```

What is the best way to automate the process? For example:

```
v1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1"), Name = c("A2")),.Names = c("ID", "Name"))             
v2 <-  structure(list(ID = c("B1"), Name = c("B2")),.Names = c("ID", "Name"))
v <- list(v1, v2)
k<-t(mapply(c, v))
```

results in:

```
ID  Name
A1  A2
B1  B2
```

not in:

```
  ID    Name
"A1","B1"   "A2","B2"
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. It mentions `cbind`, but I think you are actually looking for `rbind`. You mention `list`s, but it seems like you're actually referring to `data.frame`s. Can you please try to post some reproducible code. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips.

Comment: Thanks to Sven, code is smth like this:
'v1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1"), Name = c("A2")),.Names = c("ID", "Name"))v2 <-  structure(list(ID = c("B1"), Name = c("B2")),.Names = c("ID", "Name"))
v <- list(v1, v2)`
However, t(mapply(c, v)) does not seem to work as well.

Comment: @sven-hohenstein, thanks for the reply, but your code results in:
      ID Name
    1 A1 A2
    2 B1 B2

While I desperately need:
     ID    Name
    1 "A1","A2"  "B1","B2"

Comment: Your desperate need is not at all clear. What is the _structure_ of the thing you need? Showing its printed representation does NOT tell us its internal representation.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question *very* unclear, but maybe you can try:

```
setNames(Reduce(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ", "), v), 
         c("ID", "Name"))
#       ID     Name 
# "A1, B1" "A2, B2"
```

Or, add a `t()` in there too:

```
t(setNames(Reduce(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ", "), v), 
           c("ID", "Name")))
     ID       Name    
[1,] "A1, B1" "A2, B2"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
> data.frame(ID = do.call("paste", c(lapply(v, FUN = "[", "ID"), sep = ",")), 
+    Name = do.call("paste", c(lapply(v, FUN = "[", "Name"), sep = ",")))
     ID  Name
1 A1,B1 A2,B2
```

Comment: Great solution, but what if I have 100 names in the list? Should I define each one explicitly (i.e. NameX=do.call("paste", c(lapply(v, FUN = "[", "NameX"), sep = ",")), for each of Name1..Name100), or there is a faster way?

Comment: For many names, I would use a bit different approach. @mrdwab's solution is easily scalable to a lengthy list of names. If despite this you want to pursue this solution further, let us know.

Comment: What would you recommend memory-usage-wise?

Answer (score 0):

An idea::

```
v1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1"), Name = c("A2")),.Names = c("ID", "Name"))
v2 <-  structure(list(ID = c("B1"), Name = c("B2")),.Names = c("ID", "Name"))
v <- list(v1, v2)


t(mapply(c, v)) # output as matrix
```

Second try:

```
unlist(apply(mapply(c,v), 1, function(x) list(unlist(x))), recursive = FALSE)
# output as list
```

*Update:* If you want to have unique values within each list, use this:

```
v3 <- list(ID = "B1", Name = "B3")
vx <- list(v1, v2, v3)

unlist(apply(mapply(c,vx), 1,
             function(x) list(unique(unlist(x)))), recursive = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. What if I have a few similar elements in v1 and v2, and I do not want to double-count?

Comment: @ Sven Thanks.  Many thanks! I do apologize for bad wording of the question, what I meant is – if I have N exact lists in my list matrix, how do I ignore N-1 duplicates and have only 1 representative returned by the function, along with other lists? 
From -
$ ID  : chr [1:3] "A1" "B1" "B1" “A1”  
$ Name: chr [1:3] "A2" "B2" "B3" “A2”  
Desired Result-
$ ID  : chr [1:3] "A1" "B1" "B1"  
$ Name: chr [1:3] "A2" "B2" "B3"

Comment: I assume it has something to do with `duplicate`, looking into it now

Comment: @Alex Doesn't the last command of my answer produce the result you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, if the duplicates are stored in one row only. If not, I guess column-by-column scan using for(...) is inevitable, it seems

Comment: Could you give an example? @Alex

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the a list with the same structure as the other two, but with the elements merged. In which case, try this:

```
ul <- unlist(list(v1,v2))
sapply(unique(names(ul)),function(x) as.vector(ul[names(ul)%in%x]),simplify=FALSE)
$ID
[1] "A1" "B1"

$Name
[1] "A2" "B2"
```